# A process that has zero drift term containing itself in dB term

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, local-martingales

I want to show the following is a martingale process.($Z(t)$ continuous)
$$dZ(t)=\theta_{t}Z(t)dB_{t}$$
where $\theta_{t}$ is deterministic function
$$\theta_{t}=\sigma t$$

My trial:$$E[\int^{T}_{0}(Z(t)\theta_{t})^{2}dt]\leq E[C^{2}(\int^{T}_{0} \theta_{t}^{2}dt)]\leq+\infty
$$ 
leads to the $$\theta_{t}Z(t) \in\mathcal{H}^2$$

Comment: How are you justifying the assumption that $Z(t) \leq C$?

Comment: Oh, I thought that since $Z(t)$ is continuous, in the interval $[0,T]$, there exists a constant C that is an upper bound.

Comment: Yes but that constant depends on the sample path of $Z$ and so is itself a random variable. That is, for each $\omega \in \Omega$ (where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is your probability space) you know that $t \mapsto Z_t(\omega)$ is continuous so there is a constant $C(\omega)$ such that $Z_t(\omega) \leq C(\omega)$ on $[0,T]$. The problem is that you then take an expectation with this constant in. You don't know that $C$ is square integrable.

Comment: Thank you, I see. I have to try again.
would you mind giving me a hint, unless the problem is inadequate(not sufficient in condition)??

Comment: I forgot to say If you have solved this kind of prob before

Comment: Hint: in order for the stochastic integral $\int_0^t Z_t dB_t$ to be well defined you probably have some assumption that will tell you that $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^T Z_s^2 ds] < \infty$. The $\theta_t$ term isn't problematic since it's bounded on $[0,T]$.

Comment: Thanks I need to see the condition again

Answer (score 0):

The stochastic exponential process $z_t = 1 \cdot \exp \left[ \int_{0}^{t} \sigma_s d w_s - \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t} \sigma_s^2 ds \right]$ satisfies the sde $d z_t = \sigma_t z_t dw_t$. For $0 \leq s \leq t < \infty$ we have that

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ z_t \vert \mathcal{F}_s \right]& = \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{z_t}{z_s} z_s \vert \mathcal{F}_s \right] \\
& = z_s \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp \left[ \int_{s}^{t} \sigma_u d w_u - \frac{1}{2} \int_{s}^{t} \sigma_u^2 du \right] \vert \mathcal{F}_s \right] \\
& = z_s \exp \left[- \frac{1}{2} \int_{s}^{t} \sigma_u^2 du \right] \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp \left[ \int_{s}^{t} \sigma_u d w_u \right] \vert \mathcal{F}_s \right] \\
& =z_s \exp \left[- \frac{1}{2} \int_{s}^{t} \sigma_u^2 du \right] \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp \left[ \int_{s}^{t} \sigma_u d w_u \right] \right]  \\
& =z_s \exp \left[- \frac{1}{2} \int_{s}^{t} \sigma_u^2 du \right] \exp \left[ \frac{1}{2} \int_{s}^{t} \sigma_u^2 du \right] \\
&= z_s.
\end{align*}
$$

It is not recommended to use inequalities to prove a process is a (strict) martingale. Instead, use them to show that a process is a (strict) sub or super martingale. Equality corresponds to a strict martingale, inequality corresponds to a sub or super martingale!

Comment: I disagree with your recommendation. It is true that if the efficient method is to check the martingale property directly then you should go for equality. But very often you are given a local martingale and the efficient way to show it is a true martingale is to show it is bounded in some suitable sense (i.e. write down an inequality). Up to a small misunderstanding, it seems to me that this what OP is trying to do in the question. This can often be done in a couple of lines whilst a direct proof of the martingale property by calculating the conditional expectation would be awful.

Comment: Thank you for your view, Rhys. We will have to agree to disagree. :)